# linux virtual comport driver for ARM cortex A8

Tags: linux, embedded-linux

I have been working on this problem for quite a while now and cannot seem to find the correct driver for Linux to interface with an STM32F407. The Linux runs on an AR drone 2.0. The STM already acts as a virtual Com-port as itself when I connect it to my computer and then I can interact with it. On the AR drone 2.0 it is not listed as a COM-port but it does detect it as a USB device when I attach it. When I telnet it, it gives me this information:

```
Bus 001 device 002: ID 0483:5740 SGS Thomson Microelectronics 
Bus 001 device 001: ID 1d6b:0002
```

The first one is obviously the one I need to look at and I looked at the vendor ID on this website. http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids

this vendor ID gave me indeed the STM32F407, but I cannot find the Linux driver for this device. I was able to put the STM into a Linux computer and then looked at what driver it used. 
It was the CDC_AMC driver. I looked it up but now I have the next problem. 
it needs the virtual COM-Port driver to interact with the STM32. 
The Drone runs on a busybox Linux version v1.14.0 and I have not enough experience with Linux to know what driver I have to use and where I can find it.

Does it also have something to do with what processor it uses? In that case, the drone has a: ARM Cortex A8 1 GHz 32-bit processor

The following is seen in the output of `dmesg`:

```
usb 1-1: new full speed USB device using musb_hdrc and address 2 ecc correction in bits 939,
usb 1-1: skipped 4 descriptors after interface
usb 1-1: default language 0x0409
usb 1-1: udev 2, busnum 1, minor = 1
usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0483, idProduct=5740
usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
usb 1-1: Product: Pozyx Virtual ComPort in FS Mode
usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Pozyx Labs
usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 396D323F3336
usb 1-1: uevent
```

Comment: It's quite probable that the AR drone's kernel doesn't have support for the USB serial devices. Please can you see if one of `/proc/config` or `/proc/config.gz` exists on your drone, download it and post a link to the file.

Comment: Please also post the relevant lines from `dmesg` when plugging in the STM32.

Comment: This question would probably be better suited to Super User.

Comment: the AR drone does not allow me to have access to `/proc.`

Comment: and I do not understand what you mean with relevant lines of dmesg? what lines do you need specificly

Comment: If you run `dmesg`, you should see some lines relating to the USB device you have attached... e.g: "_device connected_", followed by some enumeration and driver information.

Comment: I've put the `dmesg` output in your question... please remove the comment.